# How to display the category id along with category name on categories list?

Tags: plugin-development, categories

I have a categories and I have to display all categories id along with categories name.

Something like

```
Accessories(id=1)

featured(id=1)
```

OR

```
id  Name
1   Accessories
2   featured
```

[image]
Is it possible to display without a plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add new column using below code. replace `(your-texanomy)` with your taxonomy slug. I have tested and its working fine. https://prnt.sc/qbibg0

```
#add header before category name
function taxonomy_custom_column_header( $columns ){

    $columns = array_slice($columns, 0, 1, true) +
    array("cat_id" => "ID") +
    array_slice($columns, 1, count($columns) - 1, true) ;

    return $columns;
}
add_filter( "manage_edit-(your-texanomy)_columns", 'taxonomy_custom_column_header', 10);

# add value to newly added column
function taxonomy_custom_column_content( $value, $column_name, $tax_id ){

    if ( 'cat_id' == $column_name ) {
        $content = $tax_id;
    }
    return $content;
}
add_action( "manage_(your-texanomy)_custom_column", 'taxonomy_custom_column_content', 10, 3);
```

Comment: Give me some time to check this.

Comment: I need to know why you use 10, 3 in add_action?

Comment: 10 is priority and 3 is number of argument.

Comment: I just copy and paste the answer in function.php. I am not getting it. do I need to change any thing in the code? check this https://prnt.sc/qbinbq I am using WordPress 5.3.1

Comment: Yes, as i mention in answer, you need to replace (your-texanomy) with your taxonomy slug from **add_filter( "manage_edit-(your-texanomy)_columns", 'taxonomy_custom_column_header', 10);** and **add_action( "manage_(your-texanomy)_custom_column", 'taxonomy_custom_column_content', 10, 3);**

Comment: You mean to say I have to use category instated of (your-texanomy). right?

Comment: Yes.. **add_filter( "manage_edit-category_columns", 'taxonomy_custom_column_header', 10);**
    **add_action( "manage_category_custom_column", 'taxonomy_custom_column_content', 10, 3);**

Comment: Yes, It's working in category. I have a doubt. I have created custom post type and I am getting the list some think like this https://prnt.sc/qbiyn4. Now if I have to displaying categorywith id then How can I display? somethink like Product-slider1-mycatgoryid

Comment: The answer works as you say yourself @NarenVerma, the `ID` is visible on the category listing. What you now suddenly also want is it be shown on the post type listing, which is another(extra) question. Perhaps you open a new question with this as question.

Comment: @Charles, Yes, I accepted.  I just ask my doubt because i have to do same on custom post. What question I have to ask some one will mark as duplicate.

Comment: There is no doubt, it works as asked, what you want now also is a little more 'complex'/different. Question for new topic could be: *How to display the Cat ID on a custom post type listing*

Comment: ok. Thanks. I'll not repeat this in future.

Comment: @ChetanVaghela, Can you help me out with this issue? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/354764/is-it-possible-not-to-define-category-on-function-php-and-add-the-shortcode-sho